# How can I craft a csv from multi level json in powershell?

Tags: json, powershell, csv, parsing, scripting

I am trying to parse a JSON response that looks like

```
{
"Objects":  [
                     {
                         "Name":  "FirstName",
                         "Type":  "XXXX",
                     },
                     {
                         "Name":  "SecondName",
                         "Type":  "YYYY",
                     },
                     {
                     "Name":  "ThirdName",
                         "Type":  "ZZZZ",
                     },
            ],
 "TotalCount":  127
 }
```

I want a CSV formatted like

```
"Name","Type"
"FirstName","XXXX"
"SecondName","YYYY"
```

and so on.
I tried creating a PSCustomObject and using Select-Object with it to generate the CSV but it does not give me the desired output.
My code:

```
$report=$null
foreach($obj in $json){
$item=$obj | ConvertFrom-Json
$report=[pscustomobject]@{
Name=($item.Objects.Name | Out-String).Trim()
Type=($item.Objects.Type | Out-String).Trim()
}
$report | Select-Object Name,Type | Export-Csv "PATH"`
```

Gives me CSV that looks like:

```
"Name","Type"
"FirstName
 SecondName
 ThirdName",
"XXXX
 YYYY
 ZZZZ"
```

Comment: have you tried just:  $json | convertfrom-json?  that should automatically convert it to a PSObject for you.  $json | converfrom-json | export-csv $path

Comment: I did try that but I end up with a CSV that has System.Object[] entries

Comment: Ah... i see there is a parent array in JSON... try: 

($json | convertfrom-json).objects | Select-Object Name,Type | Export-Csv $Path

Comment: Perfect! now I can access the objects array. How do I include TotalCount in the same csv file?

Comment: isn't total count provided by the line number of the last entry?  you'll mess up the structure of your CSV is you include "totalcount" in a CSV with headers of 'Name, Type'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you really want the total count in the csv as well, here is one thing you could do:

```
$psobjarray = ($json | convertfrom-json)
$psobjarray.objects | Select-Object Name,Type | Export-Csv $Path
"Total Count: $($psobjarray.totalcount)" | out-file $Path -append
```